# How to change password and/or connect to mysql database MAMP?

Tags: mysql, config, mamp-pro

I am not sure what I did when I was working on organizing my users in mysql database, but now I can't connect to mysql phpmyAdmin whatsover. I am using MAMP and have not been able to find research on how to re-connect or make sure all of my passwords are correct. I am getting [image] I am frankly not sure which config file is being referred to or how to access it and make sure my passwords are correct. Please let me know what else I could provide to help you help me figure this out.

I've also [tried this if you scroll down to the change password section](http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/) Despite any new password I create. I'm getting 'password YES denied'

Comment: doesn't MAMP provide its own phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: @DavidLin of course, and that's what I"m locked out of ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the information here, please do a google search before posting

http://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/resetting-mamp-mysql-root-user-password/

Comment: Plus one for a solid response and a good article, however I tried twice following those instructions and I'm still locked out.

Comment: I tried again and did some other trouble shooting but wouldnt' have been able to do it without bouncing off of what you sent. Thanks and cheers! @AntomiElectrono